# How can a array provide storage?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, stdarray

In [C++ draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-3) The first paragraph is talking about situations where an array *provides storage*:

> If a complete object is created ([expr.new]) in storage associated
> with another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type
> “array of N std​::​byte” ([cstddef.syn]), that array provides storage
> for the created object if:...

In these cases array is refering to an `unsigned char C[1]` or to `std::array`? If is the first case, I can, for example, create an object at the same memory addres of a existing array C and then this array C will *provide storage*, but only if its type is the cited above? What would happen if it was just a `char` array and not a `unsigned char` array?

Comment: _What would happen if it was just a `char` array and not a `unsigned char` array?_ You'll kill the array object, per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#1.sentence-4. However, there is a chance that «provides storage» will be extended to arrays of just `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In these cases array is refering to an unsigned char C[1] or to std::array?

"Array" refers to arrays such as `T[N]`.

"Array" doesn't  refer to `std::array`. `std::array` isn't an array, but rather it is a class template. `std::array` may contain an array as a member.

`array` (with formatting that signifies code) refers to `std::array`.

> What would happen if it was just a char array and not a unsigned char array?

Strict interpretation would be that no other type could "provide storage" for another object unless that is specified by another rule.

A loose interpretation would be that other types may provide storage, and the conditions that follow the quoted rule do not apply to them.

Comment: The question "What would happen if it was just a char array and not a unsigned char array?" is strange by my part. Its that this just makes sense for me if "provided storage" is a term that includes only those types of array just as a "hack" for future use of the expression

Comment: "other types may provide storage" this also is something that can happen indirectly even with a strict interpretation. `std::aligned_storage<L,A>::type` gets there via a somewhat roundabout way for example.